# How to connect to wireless with Kubuntu 14.04 on my Asus Desktop?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I'm attempting to connect to my wireless connection over Kubuntu. In Konsole when I run `nmcli nm` I'm getting this:

```
RUNNING-----STATE----------------WIFI-HARDWARE-------WIFI----------WWAN-HARDWARE--------WWAN 
running-----disconnected---------enabled-------------enabled-------enabled--------------disabled
```

I'm assuming this means that my wifi controller is properly installed and being recognized. I don't know how to connect to wireless or configure the connection though (I'm a total newbie to Kubuntu so I have absolutely no clue how to connect to the internet through Kubuntu over wireless). Any pointers would be appreciated.

#### UPDATE:

I tried  `sudo lshw -C network` and this is what came up:

```
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 48:5b:39:d3:3a:20
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw ip=10.0.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:f6fff000-f6ffffff memory:f6ff8000-f6ffbfff memory:fbdf0000-fbdfffff

  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64
       resources: irq:16 memory:fbefe000-fbefffff
```

So it seems to be seeing the network controller (I'm currently writing this by using my ethernet cable). It looks like it has a driver installed (correct me if I'm wrong). Still can't enable wireless though. It's currently disabled. When I looked up my network interfaces there are two. One is "lo" and one is "eth0" Which I assume is referring to my ethernet.

Output of `rfkill list all` command:

```
ferociousmadman@ferociousmadman-CM5675:~$ rfkill list all
ferociousmadman@ferociousmadman-CM5675:~$
```

UPDATE2:

chili555 seems to have answered my question,

sudo modprobe b43 && dmesg | grep b43

is what I had to type in, then I had to type in

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

So perhaps the right drivers weren't installed after all. In any case, I really appreciate the discussion and your assistance.

Comment: Do you see the Network manager icon at the upper right? Can you click on it and see your network? http://www.oulu.fi/it/graphics/nmgui.png

Comment: The problem's more complex than that. As you can probably gather from everything I've written above in the recent update. (Still can't connect by the way).

Comment: Does your wireless card need firmware? Check: sudo modprobe b43 && dmesg | grep b43

Comment: Ooo, that helped, wireless is now enabled thanks to you, now it's just an issue of connecting to the right network, which is pretty easy :) I can't tell you how grateful I am, I spent hours trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Broadcom wireless card requires firmware. With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and your wireless should now be working.

Answer (score 0):

I know a few commands that might help:

**If the device is disabled**

To list the state of all network interfaces.

```
$ rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

if any of these are disabled then here is how to bring them up

```
ifconfig ra0 up
```

to take it down

```
ifconfig ra0 down
```

remember to correctly replace ra0 with your interface (ath0 wlan0 eth0 eth1 etc etc etc!)

**To check Driver**

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

This command will list the interface and the drivers. If this does not list a driver. then you know u have a driver problem.

**To restart network manager**

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Let me know if any of this helps.

Comment: I just updated my post, none of that really helped, although I do know my Chip ID and PCI-ID now. the rfkill list all command didn't work.

Comment: did you try ifconfig wlan0 up ?

Comment: I did and it says: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.

Comment: please post the output of this command : rfkill list all

Comment: Okay I did that, and it didn't seem to do anything...                                ferociousmadman@ferociousmadman-CM5675:~$ rfkill list all
ferociousmadman@ferociousmadman-CM5675:~$

Comment: chili555 seems to have answered my question, sudo modprobe b43 && dmesg | grep b43 is what I had to type in, then I had to type in sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer. So perhaps the right drivers weren't installed after all. In any case, I really appreciate the discussion and your assistance.